# Creating a link to subscribe to a product?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need help on figuring how to make a link for my `Product` that enables users to subscribe to it. I first have my `Subscription` model:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :subscribable_id
  belongs_to :subscriber, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :subscribable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Then my `Product` model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :price
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :subscriptions, :as => :subscribable
end
```

My plan is to make my view, similar to the `DELETE` method a link to click to subscribe to a product. Here is my routes, controller and then view:

```
resources :products do
    post :subscribe_product, :on => :collection
end
```

ProductsController:

```
def subscribe_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  # Not sure what goes here next? 
  # Something like: user.subscriptions.create(:subscribable => product)
end
```

View:

```
<table>
 <% for product in @products %>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td><%= product.name %></td>
    <td><%= product.price %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', product, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Subscribe', :controller => "products", :action => "subscribe_product", :id => product.id %></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 <% end %>
</table>
```

Right now this gives a strange error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProductsController#show

Couldn't find Product with id=subscribe_product
```

Theirs 2 things,

1. Creating the method to subscribe.
2. Making the link correct.

How would I do these two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `subscribe_product` path uses POST, so you'll want to change your link to use that method:

```
<%= link_to 'Subscribe', {:controller => "products", :action => "subscribe_product", :id => product.id}, :method => :post %>
```

Your action will probably look something like this:

```rb
@product.subscriptions << Subscription.new(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

By default link_to uses GET, so your router thinks you are trying to go to ProductsController#show with the first param being the ID

```
http://yoursite.com/products/subscribe_product/5
```

This is a get request to the products controller with an id param of subscribe_product.

If you pass :method => :post to your link_to helper, it will issue a post request, which is what your router is expecting.

```
<%= link_to 'Subscribe', :controller => "products", :action => "subscribe_product", :id => product.id, :method => :post %>
```

Without posting your user model, I can't know for sure, but the method will look like this:

```
@product.subscriptions.create(:user_id => user.id)
# user.id would be current_user.id, or whatever you are storing the current user as
```